# How not to show the message "DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020."?

Tags: python-2.7, deprecated

I am constantly querying for a new version of a package. At each query I get  the python 2.7 deprecation message at the command prompt. Is there a way for me to hide it?

The complete message is:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fallowing code inside your script,

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
```

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html)